# How to log the usage of an Oracle function

Tags: oracle

In my Oracle database, I have a function `MYFCT` that is obsolete. A new version of it has been writen as `MYFCT_NEW`, that returns different output for the same input parameters.
We re-wrote our codebase accordingly, but I wonder if there is still some undocumented usage of it.

Is it possible to log the usage of a function ? Something like a trigger `CREATE TRIGGER BEFORE EXECUTE ...` to log all sessions that call `MYFCT`.

For the moment, I only imagine removing the grant to execute that function and see if errors pop up, but it seems a bit harsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include a logging procedure into the old function. Something like this:

```
SQL> create table fun_log (who varchar2(30), when date);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure p_log is
  2    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  3  begin
  4    insert into fun_log(who, when) values (user, sysdate);
  5    commit;
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.
```

This is your "old" function; include line #3 (i.e. call the `p_log` procedure):

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test return number is
  2  begin
  3    p_log;
  4    return 1;
  5  end;
  6  /

Function created.
```

Then check whether there are any rows in `fun_log` table:

```
SQL> select f_test from dual;

    F_TEST
----------
         1

SQL> select * from fun_log;

WHO                            WHEN
------------------------------ -------------------
SCOTT                          06.07.2023 10:03:12

SQL>
```

If you want, you can create a trigger on `fun_log` which will send you an e-mail whenever a new row is being inserted (so that you wouldn't have to check it manually).